# BigQuery client library throwing NPE when setting 'dryRun' to true

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, google-bigquery

According to the documentation for the `dryRun` field in the BigQuery [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), when set to `true`, the query will not be executed, but instead will validate it and return some basic statistics:

> [Optional] If set to true, BigQuery doesn't run the job. Instead, if
>   the query is valid, BigQuery returns statistics about the job such as
>   how many bytes would be processed. If the query is invalid, an error
>   returns. The default value is false.

[image]

However, using the [Java client lib for BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery), and setting `dryRun` to `true` throws a NullPointerException:

```
[...] 
JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = newBuilder(query)
                            .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                            .setUseLegacySql(false)
                            .setDryRun(true)
                            .setDestinationTable(TableId.of("<project>", "<dataset>", "<table>"))
                            .setCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                            .setWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                            .setPriority(INTERACTIVE)
                            .build();

                    JobInfo jobInfo = JobInfo.of(jobConfiguration);
                    Job job = bigQuery.create(jobInfo);
[...]
```

Exception in [JobConfiguration LN 140](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobConfiguration.java#L140):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobConfiguration.fromPb(JobConfiguration.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo$BuilderImpl.<init>(JobInfo.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.fromPb(Job.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:229)
```

Is this a bug in the Java client lib, or am I doing/using it wrong?

**Note**: setting it to `false` works as expected.

**Note2**: `jobConfiguration` and `jobInfo` are both initialised i.e. not `null`

[image]

Comment: Just a thought... Is it possible that the result of `build()` is null? I wonder if constructing the `JobConfiguration` is failing for some reason.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard: Updated question (not `null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the client library. Here is the issue in GitHub.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/525